# Getting Resource as null while creating AWS Cloudformation Stack using template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create Stack using AWS Cloudformation.
I used below Roles and Policy.
I think I have proper indentation for the Resource which it is complaining. I saw another similar issue in StackOverflow but it seems like mine is not the same issue as that of the posted question in stack overflow.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: A CCL EBS template
Resources:
  CodeForCCLEBSAPI:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: 'ccl-ebs-role-1'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: [codebuild.amazonaws.com]
        Version: '2012-10-17'
      Path: /
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: CodeForCCLEBSAPI
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Action:
                  - elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplication
                  - elasticbeanstalk:CreateEnvironment
                  - elasticbeanstalk:DeleteApplication
                  - elasticbeanstalk:RebuildEnvironment
                  - elasticbeanstalk:SwapEnvironmentCNAMEs
                  - elasticbeanstalk:TerminateEnvironment
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: "*"
              - Action:
                  - elasticbeanstalk:*
                  - ec2:*
                  - elasticloadbalancing:*
                  - autoscaling:*
                  - cloudwatch:*
                  - s3:*
                  - sns:*
                  - rds:*
                  - cloudformation:*
                Effect: Allow
                Resource: "*"
```

I am getting below error

[/Resources] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with your template nor the role. The template deploys perfectly fine (I tested it).

Comment: Thanks for replying to my question. I will try the same in my personal account. For now, it is not working in my office AWS account.

Comment: @BanditaPradhan what ever is happening it's not related to this template. Probably you are using different template then in the question.